Safari iOS 17 on iPad mini: Web content shifts down after toggling fullscreen mode on iPad
I'm optimizing a web app for iPad, and I've encountered an issue with the layout shifting after toggling fullscreen mode. Here’s what happens:

I enable fullscreen mode on the app (either through a user interaction or programmatically).
When I exit fullscreen mode, all
of the content is shifted slightly downward, leaving an unaccounted-for gap at the top of the page.
This gap is not visible in the DOM or CSS, and the content at the bottom of the page is
pushed slightly off-screen.

This issue only seems to happen on iPad, in Safari. I was not able to reproduce on an iPhone or in alternate browsers on iOS. I've tried inspecting the DOM and viewport properties, but I can’t identify what's causing the shift.
I cannot share my project, but this api demo produces the same issue on my iPad mini 6th gen: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/fullscreen.php
Here is my fullscreen code:


  requestFullscreen: async function (el, retryCount, retryDelay) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= retryCount - 1; i++) {
          let app = document.getElementById(el);
          if (app !== null) {
              if (isMobile.any()) {
                  try {
                      if (app.requestFullscreen) {
                          app.requestFullscreen();
                      } else if (app.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                          app.mozRequestFullScreen();
                      } else if (app.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                          app.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                      } else if (app.msRequestFullscreen) {
                          app.msRequestFullscreen();
                      }
                      break;
                  } catch (error) {
                      console.error('Fullscreen not allowed: ', error.message);
                  }
              }

          }
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, retryDelay));
      }
  }

  exitFullscreen: function () {
      try {
          if (document.exitFullscreen) {
              document.exitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
              document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
              document.webkitExitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
              document.msExitFullscreen();
          }
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Fullscreen not allowed: ', error.message);
      }
  }



I tried setting the apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style meta tag to black-translucent but that changed nothing.
Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
